# HTML5 Video Tag for iPad

Tags: ipad, html, video, quicktime

I'm trying to get a Quicktime (.mov) movie playing on the iPad. It doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting a black area instead of the video.

Would using the `VIDEO` tag even work for Quicktime? Does the `VIDEO` tag even support the `.mov` format?

What would be the best way to incorporate a quicktime video with the iPad? If any?

(Also, the .mov has the H.264 Codec, if that matters)

Sorry, this area of video and Apple and supported formats goes way over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Check the video section of http://www.diveintohtml5.org, it should help you out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the document was definitely very helpful. However, after I converted to .mp4, the same problem still persists. There is no video, but instead, it's just a black area. This is my code: `<video width="640" height="360" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src="VIDEO.mp4">
</video>` Am I doing anything wrong? I'm sure that the video is being found, but using Firebug, I see that it has the status of `206 Partial Content` Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that `206 Partial content` definitely is the problem. It only loads 435 KB of the video, instead of the 16 mb. Hm... anyone experience this problem before?

Comment: I can't really find any reason for that. Are you sure the video is not corrupted? Maybe try to check it with VLC first?

Comment: Semantically the tag you presented above is fine. One problem I see for your specific situation is the "autoplay" attribute which is disabled in iOS. This in itself isn't a problem except that your tag also doesn't include the "controls" attribute so if the first frame of your video asset is all black then what you'll end up with is an all black box where the video is and no means by which the user could play the video. Unless, of course, you have external controls hooked into the video object's methods...